# Sublime Text different syntax for files under a specific subdirectory

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there a way to make Sublime Text use a different syntax hilighting plugin for files inside a specific directory tree?

E.g. By default I want to use the default Javascript file type for .js files, but for files under ~/Unity/ folder I want to use Unity3d-Javascript file type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [`ApplySyntax`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ApplySyntax) package. This is a very powerful plugin that allows you to apply arbitrary regexes to several different aspects of a file (file name, contents, first line, suffix, etc.) and then assign a syntax based on them. Once installed, open ***`Preferences -> Package Settings -> ApplySyntax -> Settings-Default`*** to read all the notes and see how the regexes are set up. Then, open ***`... -> Settings-User`*** and add your custom regexes. I haven't tested this, but something along these lines should work:

```js
{
    "name": "Unity3D/UnityJavaScript",
    "rules": [
        {"file_name": ".*/Unity/.js$"}
    ]
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tweaked the rule to `{"file_name": ".*/Unity/.*\\.js$"}` and it works perfectly! Thanks!